# Datatable auto convert "0.000095" to "9.5E-05"

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, ado.net

I am filling my Dataset from excel sheet which contains data like this "0.000095". Datatable returned by dataset has all the columns of type string. But for some reasons I want the exact data that is in excel sheet instead of auto convert it to "9.5E-05".

```
  string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", connstring);
  adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting back from the exponential format to decimal format

```
Decimal.Parse("9.5E-05”, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the exact data that is in excel sheet instead of auto convert it to "9.5E-05".

That IS The exact data. Missed math in school?

What you want is the same REPRESENTATION (as a string).

Hanle that in the UI. Numbers in C# have no format - they are a value, and the VALUE is identical. To have the same format, handle the same format in the UI.

And if you ask abou the debugger - no way. The debugger shows values with a standard formatting.